# Node AWS Lambda fetch request failing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fetch

I am using `node-fetch` to perform a request to an API (hosted on AWS Lambda/API Gateway with Serverless Framework) from a lambda. The lambda is failing with the below invocation error:

```json
{
    "errorType": "FetchError",
    "errorMessage": "request to https://[API].us-east-2.amazonaws.com/[ENDPOINT] failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT [IP]:443",
    "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "message": "request to https://[API].us-east-2.amazonaws.com/[ENDPOINT] failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT [IP]:443",
    "type": "system",
    "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "stack": [
        "FetchError: request to https://[API].us-east-2.amazonaws.com/[ENDPOINT] failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT [IP]:443",
        "    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)",
        "    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)",
        "    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)",
        "    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)",
        "    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)",
        "    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)"
    ]
}
```

Here is the lambda in question with extraneous code removed:

```ts
"use strict";

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany();

  for (const user of users) {
    await fetch(...); // this is where the error occurs
  }
};
```

The code works fine locally (the code in the lambda itself as well as manaully making the request). Because of that, I thought this might be fixed by setting up a NAT for the lambda/configuring the VPC to have external internet access, though I'm not sure how to do that with Serverless Framework if that is indeed the issue. The lambda attempting to perform the fetch request is in the same VPC as the API. Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your API public? Why do you put lambda in a VPC?

Comment: This is definitely VPC related, if you look at the VPC configuration section of your lambda, does the security group have the correct openings to make the call?  Even within the same VPC, security groups can restrict the traffic.
@Marcin also makes a great point, if you don't need it within the VPC, removing it will likely solve it.

Comment: @Marcin I am using Serverless Framework defaults, I would move it outside of the VPC if it didn't also directly access an RDS instance within the VPC (with Prisma). I could look into moving the RDS access code to a REST endpoint and move the lambda outside of the VPC, however.

Comment: @Joseph King In the lambda VPC configuration settings, inbound settings have a rule for all protocols and ports within the security group, and outbound rules have a rule for all protocols and all ports for all IP addresses. Should this be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) for the lambda function. I believe an alternative solution (though possibly more expensive) is to set up a [NAT gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) for the Lambda.